# Reproducing a P2P stream via mplayer in a bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, streaming, mplayer

I would like to run `mplayer` from within a `bash shell` script
using a command such as

```
mplayer http://someURL &
```

where `someURL`  contains a fixed pattern with a variable pattern embedded, to be passed to the script as a parameter.

I have tried, but `mplayer` hangs while the same command written in the `bash` running in `gnome-terminal` works fine.

So there are options to be supplied to `mplayer`'s command line or simply this is impossible at all?

To specify the question, according to the dirkt's request, my attempts were made trying to reproduce a stream generated by `sopcast`: executing the program
`sp-sc-auth` passing to it a `sop` link connects an audio/video stream to a random port of the computer. Then `mplayer` *"plays"* the stream with a
command like this

```
mplayer http://localhost:<portnumber>/tv.asf
```

where the variable part is just the `<portnumber>`

Typing the previous command in `gnome-terminal`'s shell reproduces fairly the stream, while this doesn't happen if the same command appears in a `bash` script.

Here are the *sample* commands I wrote in the shell script:

```
 porta=$(( $RANDOM + 30000 ))
 portb=$(( $RANDOM + 30000 ))
 sp-sc-auth $1 $porta $portb 1>& /dev/null &
 mplayer http://localhost:${portb}/tv.asf
```

and the script was run passing a valid `sop-link` as the first and unique parameter. Monitoring the running processes once the script finishes unsuccessfully shows `sp-sc-auth` still running and issuing the `mplayer` command *by hand* in `gnome-terminal` correctly displays the stream.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to answer it. `mplayer` can render various formats over various transports, including http, with fixed patterns and variable patterns. If you mean "bittorrent" by "P2P stream", then no, it can't handle those, AFAIK. Please edit question and describe exactly what kind of "P2P stream" you mean, where it can be found, and what an URL for it would look like, and what protocol it represents.

Comment: I have edited and updated the question, hoping to be better understood.

Comment: There's no difference between how bash in gnome-terminal calls `mplayer`, and how a shell script calls `mplayer`. To be able to read from `localhost:<portnumber>`, **some other program**, probably `sp-sc-auth` must run, be bound to this port, and able to serve the stream. So whatever went wrong has nothing to do with mplayer, but with `sp-sc-auth`. Please edit question with the *exact* sequence of commands you ran in gnome-terminal, including any other actions, and also with your shell script. Possibly you need to run `sp-sc-auth` in the background, sleep a bit, or similar.

Comment: And just to make sure: You started the shell script that contains the `mplayer` command from the same gnome-terminal where you ran it directly, didn't you? `mplayer` needs to connect to the X server or wayland to display something; if you call the script in a different way (say, via `cron`), it won't have the permissions to do so.

Comment: Yes, I started the shell script in the same `gnome-terminal` as the direct command was issued from. But I had not thought about waiting a little between the two commands written in the shell script: the first running `sp-sc-auth` (in background, as you suggested) and the second running `mplayer`.  Maybe the time spent to type the _direct_ command is enough for the stream being bound to the input port... I will try this as soon as possible.

Comment: I have further edited my question supplying the information you requested.

Comment: First thing I'd try is definitely to add `sleep 2` or similar before the mplayer command in the script. Otherwise the script looks fine so far (just by inspection). If you can't get it to work with `sleep`, I'll try it out myself.

Comment: Thanks. Me too, I will try; it's not so easy to reproduce because it is necessary to find a valid `sopcast` link available...